# Start Point for writing own debugger extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to migrate from Eclipse based IDE to VSC for working with remote Ruby apps and I stuck with writing VSC debugger extension.

Currently, the debugger in the Ruby App and debugger part in Eclipse IDE communicates via HTTP.

I have read the known widely  article "[Debugger Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension#alternative-approach-to-develop-a-debugger-extension)" and don't have yet clear understanding how exact to do it.

In my mind I must use Server type of VSC debugger, which starts to listen HTTP on specific port and translate commands to from DAP. But I cannot get workable sample of this.

Do somebody smthng like this?

Comment: can you use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=castwide.ruby-debug or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby

Comment: No, I couldn't adapt their for my needs :(

Comment: Eclipse is open source so try to understand the Ruby debugger via HTTP